# Can't figure out why this package code is throwing the pls-00201 identifer 'Datatype' must be declared error. Please post if you can figure this out

Tags: oracle, package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE useful_pk
  IS
--
-- To modify this template, edit file PKGSPEC.TXT in TEMPLATE
-- directory of SQL Navigator
--
-- Purpose: Briefly explain the functionality of the package
--
-- MODIFICATION HISTORY
-- Person      Date    Comments
-- ---------   ------  ------------------------------------------
   -- Enter package declarations as shown below

   variable_name   datatype;

   PROCEDURE procedure_name
     ( param1 IN datatype DEFAULT default_value,
       param2 IN OUT datatype);

   FUNCTION function_name
     ( param1 IN datatype DEFAULT default_value,
       param2 IN OUT datatype)
     RETURN  datatype;

END; -- Package spec
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "USEFUL_PK" AS
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       WW_JMESA.useful_pk
   PURPOSE:

   REVISIONS:
   Ver        Date        Author           Description
   ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
   1.0        2/10/2009             1. Created this package body.
******************************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************/
function fn_end_month(in_month in varchar2,in_year varchar2 )  return date
is
 tmp_date date;
 wrong_date EXCEPTION;

PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(wrong_date,-01847);

PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(wrong_date,-01839);

begin

if nvl(substr(in_month,1,2),'00') ='00' or  nvl(substr(in_year,1,4),'0000')='0000' then
return null;
else
tmp_date:= to_date(substr(in_month,1,2)||'/'||substr(in_month,3,2) ||'/'||substr(in_year,1,4) ,'mm/dd/yyyy');
   return tmp_date;
end if;
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN wrong_date THEN
      tmp_date:= last_day(to_date(substr(in_month,1,2)||'/01/'||substr(in_year,1,4),'mm/dd/yyyy')) ;
      return tmp_date;

    WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
     RETURN tmp_date;
end fn_end_month;

function fn_end_month(in_month in varchar2 )  return date
is
 tmp_date date;
 wrong_date EXCEPTION;

PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(wrong_date,-01847);

PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(wrong_date,-01839);


begin


if nvl(substr(in_month,1,4),'0000') ='0000' or  nvl(substr(in_month,5,2),'00')='00' then
return null;
else
tmp_date:= to_date(substr(in_month,5,2)||'/'||substr(in_month,7,2) ||'/'||substr(in_month,1,4) ,'mm/dd/yyyy');
   return tmp_date;
end if;
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN wrong_date  THEN
      tmp_date:= last_day(to_date(substr(in_month,5,2)||'/01/'||substr(in_month,1,4),'mm/dd/yyyy')) ;
      return tmp_date;

    WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
     RETURN tmp_date;
end fn_end_month;


END useful_pk;
/
```

Comment: What should 'dataType' be? It is not an Oracle type, so the complier is giving error.

Comment: you are missing the execute privilege on another package that defines "datatype" , do a search for datatype in the code

Comment: @kevinsky, valid answer, but I'm pretty sure OP is just trying to compile a  template file without changing the function/procedure names.

Comment: @ruudvan quite right, I think something about Occam's razor comes into play here

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the package body from your code template to replace placeholders like `datatype` with actual valid data types, and you've replaced the function names. The package name itself is a bit unhelpful, but that's only a *real* issue if someone else had already created one from the template and left the name as it was too.

What you haven't done is change the package *specification* to match the changes to the body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE useful_pk
  IS
--
-- To modify this template, edit file PKGSPEC.TXT in TEMPLATE
-- directory of SQL Navigator
--
-- Purpose: Briefly explain the functionality of the package
--
-- MODIFICATION HISTORY
-- Person      Date    Comments
-- ---------   ------  ------------------------------------------

  function fn_end_month(in_month in varchar2,in_year varchar2 ) return date;

  function fn_end_month(in_month in varchar2 )  return date;

END; -- Package spec
/
```

You have to have both versions of the overloaded `fn_end_month` function declared in the specification to be able to call them from outside the package. And you don't want to keep the procedure and function from the template, partly because they don't have a valid data type, but mostly because if they are in the specification then they *must* also be in the body.

---

Your pragmas aren't going to do quite what you probably expect; [from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exceptioninit_pragma.htm#LNPLS01315):

> If two EXCEPTION_INIT pragmas assign different error codes to the same user-defined exception, then the later pragma overrides the earlier pragma.

So the second pragma takes precedence, and ORA-01847 will *not* be caught by the `wrong_date` exception handler. To catch both you would need to define two exceptions and add pragmas for each one, so each gets a different error code.

It's also a very bad idea to catch all other exceptions with `then others`. You will just see a null value returned (as `tmp_date` won't have been set by the statement that threw the exception), with no indication of why the supplied value wasn't valid.